# Hyphenation fails in Libre Office 3.5

Tags: libreoffice

"executing the hyphenation.:
English(UK) is not supported by the spell-check function or is not presently active.
Please check your installation and, if necessary, install the required language module
or activate it under 'Tools-Options-Language Settings-Writing Aids'.

**But it is installed and activated and  it is checking my spelling in English English (en-gb). It just won't hyphenate. A document that won't hyphenate is not of publishable quality.**

28/01/2014 Just ran sudo apt-get install myspell-en-gb which informed me that no files needed changing and none were updated i.e. it is installed in the latest version. Same result for libreoffice -l10n -en-gb

Comment: Not trying to be obtuse, but is libreoffice-l10n-en-gb installed? I assume it is but wanted to start with the basics.

Comment: Here's another entry, from the folks at Ask Libreoffice, on the need to install myspell-en-gb too: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1678/spell-checking-not-working-in-v342/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Synaptic Package Manager installed on your system?

1.If not open up your Ubuntu Software Center,type Synaptic Package Manager into the search box and install.You must be the admin to do this.
2.Once the Synaptic Package Manager has installed,open it and type LibreOffice into the search box.A list of LibreOffice software will appear.
3.Look for LibreOffice hyphenation,right click on it and choose "Reload" the program.This will reinstall the hyphenation software and as a bonus will alert you to other LibreOffice software that may be corrupted or missing.

Comment: One way or another you have helped me solve the problem. I honestly believe I have the solution. There is no package libreoffice-hyphen-en-gb. It does not exist. The solution is to change the language of the text to en-us then it hyphenates before my very eyes.